# How to abstract Linq2SQL for testability

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, testability

I'm working on a project that uses Linq2SQL for data access. The project is made up of an ASP.NET MVC application and 8 class libraries. Most of the class libraries have their own L2S data classes.

As part of the work I'm doing, I'm trying to get the various components under test to introduce some stability clean up the codebase, it currently makes heavy use of static classes and methods, and the controllers have static DataContexts which are used throughout.

How can I refactor the L2S usage so that I can test the controller actions?

I've introduced dependency injection into the app to decouple some of the other services but I  don't want the DataContext as a dependency  property of the controllers because I want to control the instantiation of the DataContexts and their DataLoadOptions.

One thing I did try was taking advantage of the partial classes that L2S generates and added an Interface to the DataContexts, but I found that the abstraction bubbled it's way up into the application rather than staying down in the class libraries. It didn't feel like the right way of doing things and that it would be a pain to maintain. Has anyone had any particular success or failure with this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Repository pattern to hide `DataContext` inside. Repositories are abstractions, so suite really nice with Dependency Injection principle.

For instance, you define some repository.

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User Get(int id);
    User Save(User user);
    void Delete(User user);
}
```

The implementation is something like

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private MyDataContext _context;

    UserRepository() 
    {
        _context = new MyDataContext();
    }

   // ...

}
```

Now, controller depends only on interface.

```
public UserController : Controller
{
    UserController(IUserRepository userRepository) { }
}
```

So, it's perfectly testable since you can mock `IUserRepository` in your tests.

Comment: This will abstract over LINQ to SQL but it will also remove all of its features. With this scheme, we are back to typed datasets.

Comment: I don't see a way to execute queries. Most interesting applications require queries which do more than filter and orderby. You need a generic querying facility.

Comment: I use this pattern when writing pure unit tests for my controllers, and I think it works well. I mainly write actual integration tests when I write my DAL tests

Comment: It is worth noting that the data context should be disposed appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

While [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx) refers to testability of using the entity framework, the high level concept can be applied here.

The heart of the examples outline using the "Unit of Work" pattern with the "Repository" pattern. The Unit of Work is an abstraction around the data context and represents the working set for a particular controller, or set of similar controllers. You can include multiple repositories in the unit, and since the repositories are based on `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` you can still take advantage of LINQ functionality.

Testability options include mocking out the Unit and Repositories, or creating in-memory representations for testing purposes.